# Rust serde get runtime heap size of Vec<serde_json::Value>

Tags: rust, serde

I'm making a rust tool which migrates data using the REST API of an internal service. Essentially, it makes a GET request, the returned data is an array of JSON objects which is deserialized into a struct field of type `serde_json::Value`, gets a mutable array of it (as_array_mut) for a bit of processing and POSTs the result to another REST API.

This is done in batches of say, 10000 records per request, however the data can unpredictably change in size. Usually it's around 10MiB but sometimes it can jump to over 400MiB which can easily crash the internal service.

Because of this, I want a way to control how many records can be fetched per request based on the size of the response data, in other words, the heap size of `Vec<serde_json::Value>` during runtime. I've tried `std::mem::size_of_val` and the crate `heapsize` but they didn't work. I think one work around would be converting it to a string and get its length (the size doesn't have to be 100% accurate, a rough estimate is fine too) but that would mean there will be two copies of the JSON data. This is my last option but I wanted to know if there's any other alternative and efficient way to get the heap size.

Update - (response to @Caesar):
I was temporarily using this while waiting for any better approaches:
`let size = serde_json::to_vec(docs)?.len();`

Thanks to @Caesar I did a few benchmarking and here's what I got. `size` is is from what I mentioned above, `size_new` and `size_new_for` is from Caesar's answer, difference being the first one uses `.map(|v| { sizeof_val(v) }).sum()` and the second is a simple for-in loop which increments the result to a variable.

```
rows: 1000
size raw: 1360727, fmt: 1.30 MiB, took: 4.980794ms
size_new raw: 3834194, fmt: 3.66 MiB, took: 716.486µs
size_new_for raw: 3834194, fmt: 3.66 MiB, took: 672.523µs

rows: 10000
size raw: 17778816, fmt: 16.96 MiB, took: 62.151661ms
size_new raw: 43805986, fmt: 41.78 MiB, took: 8.775323ms
size_new_for raw: 43805986, fmt: 41.78 MiB, took: 8.158837ms

rows: 50000
size raw: 84354219, fmt: 80.45 MiB, took: 199.82163ms
size_new raw: 175919470, fmt: 167.77 MiB, took: 26.010926ms
size_new_for raw: 175919470, fmt: 167.77 MiB, took: 27.084353ms
```

Ignoring the timings, there seems to be a huge difference in size from turning the entire thing to a vector of bytes (serde_json::to_string takes over 2 times longer than serde_json::to_vec but gives the same result). I'm sort of confused as to which one is an over-estimate here, isn't turning the entire thing to a string/byte array supposed to be an over-estimate or have I been using a grossly under-estimated approximation this whole time?

Here's the complete code:

```
let size = serde_json::to_vec(docs)?.len() as u64;
let size_new: usize = docs.iter().map(|v| {
    sizeof_val(v)
}).sum();
let mut size_new_for = 0;
for v in docs.iter() {
    size_new_for += sizeof_val(v);
}
```

Comment: You can always recurse and check the size.

Comment: Why would you "convert to string"? Isn't the data you get in string form to begin with? You could check the size of the body before deserializing it.

Comment: @user4815162342 The response is in JSON format  and is immediately deserialized into a struct by reqwest::Response .json()

Comment: Every `String` and `Vec` in Rust always has 24 bytes of overhead (on a 64 bit system) even when empty, and `Map` iirc has even more. It's not too surprising that the JSON string representation requires fewer bytes than the in-memory representation. Ultimately, measure your RSS. Also, where you can, avoid the use of `serde_json::Value` and [define](https://serde.rs/derive.html) proper rust `struct`s that match your JSON structure. That should help with memory usage and speed.

Comment: @Caesar Oh I see, so just converting the whole thing to a string/Vev<u8> is a much better approximation. Unfortunately I can't define a struct since the fields/keys are completely dynamic (It's like fetching data from a schema-less database)

Comment: If the String is the better approximation, I really don't know what you're trying to approximate.

Comment: (I'm also unsure why you expected a difference between the `for`-form and the `map`-`sum`-form. Those are guaranteed to have the same result.)

Comment: @LollyPopLolly You don't need to call `.json()`, you can get the body as a string to begin with, then check the size, and finally (if the size is ok) call `serde_json::from_str()` to convert it (which is what `json()` does for you). You never need to convert from JSON to string, because that runs an extra conversion and just spends time and memory without need.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the exact memory size of a `serde_json::Value` is somewhat tricky for several reasons

- You can't access the underlying `Map` class and ask what capacity its backing allocation has
- Allocators have overhead, so even if you know the allocated size, that doesn't translate directly into how much memory you'll need.

In any case, the following function might provide a workable approximation.

```
fn sizeof_val(v: &serde_json::Value) -> usize {
    std::mem::size_of::<serde_json::Value>()
        + match v {
            serde_json::Value::Null => 0,
            serde_json::Value::Bool(_) => 0,
            serde_json::Value::Number(_) => 0, // Incorrect if arbitrary_precision is enabled. oh well
            serde_json::Value::String(s) => s.capacity(),
            serde_json::Value::Array(a) => a.iter().map(sizeof_val).sum(),
            serde_json::Value::Object(o) => o
                .iter()
                .map(|(k, v)| {
                    std::mem::size_of::<String>()
                        + k.capacity()
                        + sizeof_val(v)
                        + std::mem::size_of::<usize>() * 3 // As a crude approximation, I pretend each map entry has 3 words of overhead
                })
                .sum(),
        }
}
```

A few thoughts (mostly linux-centric):

- If you need precise memory sizes, you might be better off by directly measuring your process's memory size via `procfs::process::Process::myself().unwrap().status().unwrap().vmrss.unwrap() * 1024`. The caveat here is that allocators tend to not give memory back to the OS that quickly, so you might over-estimate.
- If you're using a custom allocator, you might be able to directly [ask it](https://docs.rs/tikv-jemalloc-ctl/latest/tikv_jemalloc_ctl/#examples) for memory usage statistics.
- Instead of worrying about controlling the size, you could let the OS warn you about impeding memory overusage by registering an `eventfd` on `memory.oom_control` (but I think you may have to implement that yourself, I don't see a convenient crate for it).
- (The `loupe` crate also implements allocation size measuring, but I don't think it supports `serde_json`.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I updated the post with a few questions based on the code you provided. Btw I don't think I can use tikv-jemalloc or procfs since I also use a fork pool to migrate collections at the same time.